# Python module import in MATLAB cannot be found or imported

Tags: python, matlab, import

I want to import a python module to matlab with this command:

```
import mapalign.embed
```

However, this results in the error:

```
Error using import
Import argument 'mapalign.embed' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
```

When I try to import mapalign.embed in Python (2.7) with `from mapalign import embed`, then it works just fine. I've also checked the python path in matlab with `py.sys.path` and the directory containing mapalign is listed in the path.

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need to import into Matlab, but simply use it with syntax like what you do for py.sys.path:

```
py.mapalign.embed
```

Comment: This produces the error: `Undefined variable "py" or class "py.mapalign.embed".`. Note that other py methods work, so this is not an issue relating to py itself not being found.

Comment: You may have multiple python installed. You will need tell Matlab which version you want to use by pyversion 'pyFolder\python.exe'

Comment: Just checked the python version in MATLAB - it is already pointing towards the correct version (2.7).

Comment: what would you use it in python? You need to provide the arg for py.mapalign.embed as you do in python.

Comment: It's called with a numpy array and an integer, both of which I can create with py.numpy.array() and py.int(), respectively. Calling py.mapalign.embed with these variables results in the same error though.

Comment: Is the package one of those that are not supported for now? Here is a list: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-python-support.html

Comment: Nope, it doesn't fall into any of those categories as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You *don't need* to use `import` statement for the *Python* module in *MATLAB* - simply use the form

```
py.mapalign.embed...
```

in the place where you in Python use

```
import mapalign.embed
mapalign.embed...
```

---

Instead of

```
import mapalign.embed
```

(which is the command for *Python*)
you *may* use

```
import py.mapalign.embed
```

which *is* the command for *MATLAB*, but pay attention:

It is *not* an equivalent to Python's

```
import mapalign.embed
```

*Its meaning is similar to Python's

```
from mapalign import embed
```

as the `import` statement does not have the same functionality in *MATLAB* as in *Python*:

*Python*    uses the `import` statement to *load and make code accessible*.
*MATLAB* uses the `import` function to refer to a class or function *without using the package name*.

Comment: `import py.mapalign.embed` produces the same error as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Install Python (Cpython) from python.org/downloads.
Make sure the version you download is 64-bit if your Matlab exe is 64-bit. By default, a 32-bit cersion of python is downloaded so be careful.
Open python and try the command "import numpy as np". If you get an error, you need to install the library. For this, go to command prompt and type (for python 3): "pip3 install numpy"
Now you will be able to use numpy library in matlab